# Why there is no insert() in Spring JDBCTemplate?

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

I noticed that Spring JDBCTemplate is using update() method for insert,update and delete operations.

I am curious to know Why methods like jdbcTemplate.insert() and jdbcTemplate.delete() are not available?

Any good reasons behind this design decision?

Comment: because there is no Need for it. Update is or all manipilationd queries: "Issue a single SQL update operation (such as an insert, update or delete statement) using a PreparedStatementCreator to provide SQL and any required parameters."

Comment: The name is about the action of updating the database. Not about the insert/update/delete concept of the SQL

Comment: When I am performing an  insert operation/action, Why should I call it as "update" , unless there is no good reason?. What is the problem/reason to give meaningful names to methods?

Comment: @Jens, Yes, update() is capable of doing multiple opearations, but I don't think it is following Single Responsibility Principle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you may know Spring JDBCTemplate intended for boilerplate termination. To be more specific here is the table

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

So basically saying they don't invent something new. It's some kind of wrapper. And if you will look inside  `jdbcTemplate.update(..)` you will see java.sql.PreparedStatement that has only `executeUpdate()` `executeQuery()` `execute()`.

`executeQuery()`for getting the data from database

`executeUpdate()`for insert,update,delete

`execute()` any kind of operations

So each method responsible for particular SQL queries.

Comment: I am convinced with these lines - "So basically saying they don't invent something new. It's some kind of wrapper", then, executeUpdate() from PreparedStatement is violating SRP?

Comment: No it's not. Take a look at this from another point of view...not like - 
one method for insert second for delete e.t.c. but like - one method for sql queries.

Comment: Then, they can merge executeQuery() and executeUpdate(), right?

Comment: No,they can't. One of them returns ResultSet and another int.
So one of them responsible for getting data from DB. 2nd one for inserting/updating/deleting.

Comment: from your comment, they created separate method because of different return types, not different responsibility, Assume, if the return type is same, then Can they merge it?, 2nd one for inserting/updating/deleting => means more than one responsibility?

Comment: Let's imagine we have only one method. What data should contain resultSet if we are making delete or insert? Why should i create resultSet if i need to return only changed rows count?
About SRP. I bielive that there some abstraction takes place. You can give more specific responsiblities: method for inserting, for inserting to ONE table only, for inserting only into one ROW. And on PreparedStatement level there is only one general abstraction - run sql query.(And here we go little bit higher and devide by returning value...try to unswer my previous question and you will understand why).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116592/discussion-between-ivan-lymar-and-sundararaj-govindasamy).

Comment: Thanks for nice brainstorming :-) , BTW chat restricted in my network.